# Bash Shell Programing

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print the stars below on the screen using for or while loop. I don't know if I should treat as a string or what. If it is a string should I use foreach loop, just don't know where to start really.

```
******************
   ***********
     *******
       ***
        *
```

I am trying to get it to work even though I know it is wrong, but I am trying. Thanks for the advice.

```
#!/bin/bash

whilefunc() {
    echo "*************"
    echo"  ******  "
    echo"   ****   "
 }

i=2

while [ $i = 2 ]
do
    whilefunc
done

exit
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far, some code available?

Comment: Nobody will do your homework for you. People here can help but you have to try something.

Comment: @LucM The trouble is, they will...

Comment: If this is homework, please add a "homework" tag.

Comment: Keith thanks this is not a homework at all. I'm doing this on my own, just don't know which loop to use sine * is not a number and I don't know if I have to treat it as a string

Comment: @ascii-lime: The suggestion was valid when I made it. I'm aware that the homework tag has now been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Any loop will do, and just escape the * with backslash i.e.

```
while [[ : ]]; do
  echo -e \*****
  echo -e  \***
  echo -e   \*
  # do whatever else you need to do
done
```

Comment: thanks my friend the only thing I guess it will run for ever I just wanted to run once